# A word to describe a person who loves anything related to celebrities/gossips/trends and is easily affected by them

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, expressions, phrase-requests, synonyms

I'd like to know a word to describe a person who loves celebrities, gossips, trends or anything that is popular and is
easily affected by them.

> She said she had moved to Paris because she loved "Emily in Paris" on
> Netflix. It seems that she is such a "  "!

I came up with "sheep"(https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sheep), but I'd appreciate it if you could tell me other words to describe such a person better or more accurately.

Comment: Words I might use : **enchanted** , enthralled , influenceable , flunkey , acolyte , groupie !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> She said she had moved to Paris because she loved "Emily in Paris" on
> Netflix. It seems that she is so **starstruck**.

> **Starstruck** (adj.)
>
> Fascinated by famous people, especially those connected with the
> entertainment industry; overwhelmed or greatly impressed by the
> presence of a celebrity.
>
> **1936**   *Rhinelander* (Wisconsin) *Daily News* 9 Nov. 4/3   Shirley
> Temple always carries an autograph book, like any star-struck
> youngster. [OED]

> **star-struck** (adj.)
>
> *Often disapproving*
>
> Feeling great or too much respect for famous or important people,
> especially famous actors or performers
>
> *It's the story of a star-struck young girl who goes to Hollywood to make her fortune.* [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/star-struck)